# In Royden, a set $E$ is measurable iff $m(E \triangle U) < \epsilon$ where $U$ is a finite union of intervals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> A set $E$ with $m(E) < \infty$ is measurable iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a finite union $U$ of intervals such that $m(E \triangle U) < \epsilon$.

I am able to prove one way, i.e. $E$ measurable implies $m(E \triangle U) < \epsilon$, but have no insight on how to prove the other way.

Comment: If you are asking about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, you should state that in the beginning. In fact, you haven't defined $m$ at all. You also really need to deal with the quantifiers more correctly: both $\epsilon$ and $U$ have an implicit quantifier here which you didn't give.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6005's comment above is right. I'll give an answer to what I believe you're asking. Let $m$ be Lebesgue outer measure and suppose $m(E \triangle U) < \epsilon/2$. It's sufficient to show that for all $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $$m(A) \geq m(A \cap E) + m(A - E).$$

Note that $$A \cap E = (A \cap E \cap U) \cup ((A \cap E) - U)$$ and $$A-E = (A - (E \cup U)) \cup ((A \cap U) - E).$$

Then, using the above, monotonicity, and the fact that $U$ is measurable, we have
$$\begin{align} m(A \cap E) + m(A-E) &\leq m(A \cap E \cap U) + m(A \cap E) - U) + m(A - (E \cup U)) + m((A \cap U) - E) \\ &\leq m(A \cap U) + m(E - U) + m(A - U) + m(U - E) \\ &\leq 2m(E \triangle U) + m(A) \\ &\leq \epsilon + m(A).  \end{align}$$

But as $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary we can conclude.

Comment: why is m(E-U) + m(U-E) <= m(E symm diff U)?

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh It's not. I use $m(E-U) + m(U - E) \leq 2m(E \triangle U)$. Note that, in general, $m(A) + m(B) \leq 2m(A \cup B)$ by monotonicity.

Comment: In you second to last inequality, $m(A \cap U) +  m(A - U) \leq m(A)$ is not generally true. If you use only open set $A$(It's enough to test only open set)

Comment: @Beginner It's true (with equality) for measurable $U$. That's just the definition of Lebesgue measurability.